# Hardy's inequality can be improved?

Tags: reference-request, inequalities, differential-inequalities

Hardy's inequality in $L^{p}$-spaces, taking the form [3]

$${\displaystyle \left\|{\frac {f}{|x|}}\right\|_{L^{p}(R^{n})}\leq {\frac {p}{n-p}}\|\nabla f\|_{L^{p}(R^{n})},2\leq n,1\leq p<n,}$$
where

${\displaystyle f\in C_{0}^{\infty }(R^{n})}$, and where the constant
${\displaystyle {\frac {p}{n-p}}}$ is known to be sharp.

I want to know if this condition ${\displaystyle f\in C_{0}^{\infty }(R^{n})}$ can be improved, that is, if this inequality holds for $f \in L^p$ spaces in general, or if it holds for spaces of functions that I can approximate by a sequence ${\displaystyle f_n\in C_{0}^{\infty }(R^{n})}$ and pass the limit while preserving the inequality? I've seen this for Gagliardo-Nirenberg's inequality, but I don't know if it works for Hardy's inequality.

Any references that allow me to go deeper into the subject are welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: It is valid in $W^{1,p}$, for the same values of $p$, for example.

Comment: but can you explain how to get it in $W^{1,p}$? Is it some density argument? Can you pass some reference?

Comment: Just take a sequence $(f_n)\in C_0^\infty$ convergent to $f$ in $W^{1,p}$ and almost everywhere. Apply Hardy to each $f_n$ and let $n \to \infty$, using Fatou for the term $f/|x|^2$. Or, if you wish, apply Hardy to $f_n-f_m$ to show that $(f_n/|x|^2)$ is Cauchy. The same proof works for $f \in L^{p*}$ such that $\nabla f \in L^p$.

Comment: I see, it's a simple argument, but very useful. Using Fatou's Lemma with convergence almost always allows you to pass the limit on the left side at $u_n$, without worrying about the $|x|^{-2}$ term. I don't know why the authors don't put these observations, it would be very useful for those who are still learning. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Another possibility is to apply Hardy to the differences $f_n-f_m$ to get the convergence of $f_n/|x|^2$. Then you need to identify the limit as $f/|x|^2$ and then a.e. converges is needed again.